# problem with importing from lazypredict, it does not contain any function or method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

I installed lazypredict but it does not have any method

```py
import lazypredict
#from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier

print(lazypredict.__version__)
dir(lazypredict)

0.2.7
['__author__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__email__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__']
```

I have tried with different version of lazypredict(0.2.7, 0.2.8, 0.2.11) with different version sklearn (0.23.1,0.24, and 1.2.1) in python 3.8 and 3.9. but the outcome is the same.

if I uncomment the line `from lazypredict.Supervides ...` I will get this error:

edited: include full error track

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/v8/gy4lk66j5jv7krxs16hk5wzh0000gn/T/ipykernel_42613/1479214520.py in <module>
      1 import lazypredict
----> 2 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
      3 
      4 print(lazypredict.__version__)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lazypredict/Supervised.py in <module>
     28 
     29 # import catboost
---> 30 import lightgbm
     31 
     32 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py in <module>
      6 from pathlib import Path
      7 
----> 8 from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger
      9 from .callback import early_stopping, log_evaluation, print_evaluation, record_evaluation, reset_parameter
     10 from .engine import CVBooster, cv, train

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in <module>
    108 
    109 
--> 110 _LIB = _load_lib()
    111 
    112 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in _load_lib()
     99     if len(lib_path) == 0:
    100         return None
--> 101     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
    102     lib.LGBM_GetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    103     callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    458 
    459     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 460         return self._dlltype(name)
    461 
    462     __class_getitem__ = classmethod(_types.GenericAlias)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    380 
    381         if handle is None:
--> 382             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    383         else:
    384             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Users/nz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: <D21A7969-4567-3BC7-94ED-6A9E83AE9D78> /Users/nz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Comment: Please include the full exception and traceback. It's _most recent call last_, so cutting off the bottom hides all the important stuff

Comment: There *aren't* any functions or methods in the top-level module of this package.  You have to import from a sub-module to get anything useful.  (Your traceback message is truncated, so we can't tell what went wrong with that.)

Comment: use ```dir(LazyClassifier)``` The same goes for LazyRegressor If you are trying to view available methods in lazypredict.supervised. The package lazypredict doesn't have its own methods.

Comment: Tx, I included full error track

Comment: @TiredButAwake , getting `No module named 'LazyClassifier'`

Answer (score 0):

```
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier

print(lazypredict.__version__)
print(dir(LazyClassifier))



OUTPUT:
0.2.12
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'fit', 'provide_models']
```

When using a library that inherits methods from another model you may not see them listed. `dir()` only shows methods that are directly in the object you are inspecting. So you won't be able to see the methods that are inherited from another object. What may be more insightful would be using `help(LazyClassifier)`

Comment: The same error persists for the second line.

Comment: Try reinstalling your dependencies. More specifically libomp, from the errors being read.

Comment: I tried `brew install libomp` but the problem persist